# Puppeteer XMLHttpRequest inside page.evaluate is blocking code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer

I am trying to do a GET request inside the page to get some data asynchronously, but the page.goto always gets blocked and waits till the GET request finishes before being executed.

I have a piece of code like this in a separate module:

```js
var requestSite = "https://somerequest.com";
// something
return await page.evaluate(async requestSite => {
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", requestSite, true);
        req.onload = () => {
            if (req.status === 200) {
                resolve(req.responseText);
            }
        };
        req.send();
    });
}, requestSite);
```

Main module:

```js
page.goto("https://somesite.com");
```

How do I make it nonblocking in this situation?

Comment: That whole `new Promise(...)` thing can be replaced with a simple `fetch(requestSite).then(response => { if (!response.ok) { throw new Error(response.status); } else { return response.text(); } })`

Comment: @Andreas I believe `fetch` requires some additional package and/or specifc JS version, which is not always possible in a project.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return the promise

```js
return page.evaluate(requestSite => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", requestSite, true);
        req.onload = () => {
            if (req.status === 200) {
                resolve(req.responseText);
            }
            else {
                reject(req);
            }
        };
        req.send();
    });
}, requestSite);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it non-blocking, you need to drop all the "return await" in the function that uses `page.evaluate` (as stated in this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564391/3482730), and drop the `await` when you call it:

Ex:

```js
async function doesPageEvaluate() {
    return page.evaluate(requestSite => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", requestSite, true);
            req.onload = () => {
                if (req.status === 200) {
                    resolve(req.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    reject(req);
                }
            };
            req.send();
        });
    }, requestSite);
}

...

doesPageEvaluate(); // next line will be executed before this finishes
await page.goto("https://somesite.com");
```

Otherwise you can use `Promise.all` to run multiple promises at the same time and wait for them:

```js
// starting "page.evaluate" and "page.goto" simultaneously:
await Promise.all([
    page.evaluate(async requestSite => {
            return await new Promise(resolve => {
                ...
            });
        }, requestSite),
    page.goto("https://somesite.com")
]).then(([promise1result, promise2result]) => {

    console.log("Promises finished.");

});
```